# Identifying where colum entry first changes sign and save entry row to file

Tags: python

I have a file with multiply entries, I would like to monitor where a given column entries first change sign (i.e negative to positive) so that I save that row where this first happens to another file. In the example below, i want to monitor the change in sign in the first column.

`-1 2 3

-3 3 5

-1 4 9

-3 5 6
-2 7 7

1 3 5

2 4 5

-2 4 5

1 5 6`

The code should save the line `-2 7 7` to another file. This should be simply but am failing to do it

Comment: Please clarify if you only want the first sign change or every sign change.

Answer (score 0):

You can use zip() to process items in a list with their successor:

```
lines = [ [-1, 2, 3],
          [-3, 3, 5],
          [-1, 4, 9],
          [-3, 5, 6],
          [-2, 7, 7],
          [1,  3, 5],
          [2,  4, 5],
          [-2, 4, 5],
          [1,  5, 6]
        ]

col = 0
keepLine = [ a for a,b in zip(lines,lines[1:]) if a[col]*b[col]<0 ]
print(keepLine) # [[-2, 7, 7], [2, 4, 5], [-2, 4, 5]]


# iterative ...
col = 0
previousLine = None
for line in lines:  # or [int(n.strip()) for n in file.readline().split(",")]
    if previousLine and line[col]*previousLine[col] < 0:
        print(previousLine)
    previousLine = line
```

Comment: The input is coming from a file and so it will need an iterative approach. Not sure the initialization as shown for `lines` is helpful.

Comment: How big is your file ? It would nee to be quite huge for it not to fit in memory.  I'll add an iterative example...

Comment: Not fitting memory was not what I was pointing at. But as for the iterative, yes that is correct.

Comment: Did you mean you need help on how to go about reading / writing to files ?

Comment: No. Note, I am not the OP. I was merely saying your example is static and for a beginner who is referencing your answer it will solve that one example but it doesn't suggest the approach that should be taken. So even just a note that that is what needs to be done (reading lines and parsing) is fine.

Comment: I see, my bad.  I'll let the OP decide if that is enough info at this point.

Answer (score 0):

So I'll leave the part of reading from a file (for which there are many examples here or elsewhere) to you.

Once you do you'll have a list of lines. At this point you should use a 2-pointer approach or just an index even. Note, these lines will be string representations of the numeric entries. So you could use regular expressions to see if the line starts with a `-` or `+` or no sign (indicating positive). Or typecast or use a helper to keep it easy to manage.

```
def get_sign(line):
    sign = line.split()[0] #This will be a list of strings like ['-1', '3', '3'] or ['2', '4', '7']
    if int(sign) < 0: #That's why the need to cast to compare.
        return -1
    return 1

#in your program, after parsing the file and loading up the lines as a list of strings
curr_sign = get_sign(lines[0]) #This will either be -, +
for ind in range(len(lines)-1): #lines is from getting all the lines from the file
    if curr_sign != get_sign(lines[ind+1]):
        write_to_file(lines[ind])
        break #if you only need the first sign change.
```

If you want all sign changes to be tracked similarly

```
#in your program, after parsing the file and loading up the lines as a list of strings
curr_sign = get_sign(lines[0]) #This will either be -, +
for ind in range(len(lines)-1): #lines is from getting all the lines from the file
    if curr_sign != get_sign(lines[ind+1]):
        write_to_file(lines[ind]) #You're writing the prev line to when the sign changed
        if curr_sign < 0:
            curr_sign = 1
        else:
            curr_sign = -1
```